# Exclude rows which have same values in different columns

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I have a dataframe with ten columns:

```
A  B   C   1  1  1  1  1  1  1
B  M   J   2  1  2  2  2  2  2
J  K   Z   3  3  3  3  3  3  3.1
V  N   I   4  4  4  4  4  4  4
```

I want to exclude those rows that have the same value from 4 to 10 column. I found solution for comparing different rows but here I am talking about within 1 row. So output is

```
B  M   J   2  1  2  2  2  2  2
J  K   Z   3  3  3  3  3  3  3.1
```

because 1st and last row has same values in columns 4 to 10. I can do it by comparing each value 1 by 1 but my dataframe is very big (~100,000 rows).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What about something like:

```
 ##Work out the rows to keep
 ##dd is your data frame
 rows = apply(dd[, 4:10], 1, function(i) length(unique(i)) > 1)
```

then subset as normal

```
 dd[rows,]
```

~100K rows isn't that much.

Comment: If speed is a concern, `function(i)any(i[-1] != i[1])` will be faster than using `unique`.